# AutoMapper: how map very complex object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a `Chat` object with a `Users` field. It's an array (`IQueryable`) of `User` objects.

Each `User` object has fields like `Name`, `E-mail`, etc.

How can I map this `Chat` object in a way that `ChatDTO` object will have the field `Users` available as a string? I want the string to be only the names of users separated by comma.

That is, how do I transform an array of objects to one string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should look something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Chat, ChatDTO>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Users, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            src => string.Join(",", src.Users.Select(u => u.Name))));
```

Assuming the following classes:

```
public class Chat
{
    public IQueryable<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class ChatDTO
{
    public string Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I have a next stuck: without any exception, AutoMapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() - has no any errors, but when I try to receive via web-api list of resources (chats) - I have next error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.   - As I understand AutoMapper try to translate all that mapping into expression and can't. In result - web server can't give list of chats and return err500.